# Why one should use Consumer and Producer instead of normal getter/setter?

Tags: java

Is there any sense in replacing something like this

**1. normal version**

```
// 1.1
public getUser(){
    return user;
}

// 1.2
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

to something like this:

**2. functional version**

```
// 2.1
public Supplier<User> getUser = () -> user; 
// 2.2
public Consumer<User> setUser = (user) -> this.user = user;
```

Are there any technical benefits (e.g. performance) using version 2?

Which one should one prefer?

Comment: Hard to say without any context. Do you have an example where Pattern 2 is used?

Comment: There are methods working with Supplier and Consumer instances, for example the Stream API

Comment: I think overall the second one should perform worse. And there's pretty much zero benefit to it.

Comment: If you need a Supplier or Consumer (for example for the Stream API), you can always do `MyClass::getUser` which produces equivalent code to what you manually wrote in Pattern 2.

Comment: @Thilo in any context where get and set is needed..

Comment: Why should it be cleaner? It is opinion-based. The advantage of a supplier depends on the context, it is more usable with Observable pattern. But it's not more readable to me. plus the supplier could be easily obtained in version 1. with YourClass::getUser

Comment: A lot of reflection or code-generation based libraries understand getters and setters. Not sure they will be able to work with the extra indirection in Pattern 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't see the benefit of the functional version here. If you're looking for a way to pass getters and setters around, you can just use function references. For example, assuming that `Entry` contains methods `getUser` and `setUser`:

```
Entry entry = ...;
doSomethingWith(entry::getUser);
writeTo(entry::setUser);
```